# Ubuntu 20.04 4k resolution issue (Black Screen)

Tags: display, display-resolution, hdmi

I have big problem with my PC.

I have buied used MSI CUBI P120 without operating system. I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 and in this time was this little PC was pluged on my 1080p display. I have 4k tv (3840x2160) and i've connected with HDMI to this PC and when I booted, I have a bleck screen. Nothing showing up.

Behind the TV I have a VGA connector and I've tried to connect to VGA and works (1080p), but I dont have a sound.

Then I have connected both cable to PC (HDMI and VGA). Display settings show me for VGA is **1920x1080** and for HDMI **4096x2160** and I belive that's the reson why is my **BLACK SCREEN**.

How can I remove permanently this RESOLUTION from Ubuntu or can I set the maximal RESOLUTION **3840x1080**.

**THANKS**

Comment: Sorry type mistake. I want the maximal resolution 3840x2160.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer that can be accepted, but rather a quickfix, and also a hint for the folks with similar issues, that would like to automate monitors management.

You can set monitor resolution with **xrandr**. First use it to read what kind of resolution on what type of connection you have. Simply type `xrandr` into console.

This is output for one of my monitors:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4803 x 3240, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+963+2160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
```

so to set this monitor as is now, I can use command:

`xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 963x2160 --rotate normal`

I hope you can see corelation between output of the xrandr command and the next command, where you have to pass it.

`eDP-1` is a name of connection/port (it can be DP or HDMI) and converts into `--output eDP-1`

`primary` states that this monitor will be primary one and the sidebar with applications will be displayed on it.

`1920x1080+963+2160` converts into `--mode 1920x1080 --pos 963x2160`

And how this could help for the author of this issue?
Into ~/.bashrc file (or other rc file) you can set an alias that will trigger this command and will set up entire monitor setup with singe click of an enter

```
alias monitorsetup1='xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 964x2160 --rotate normal --output DP-2-1 --mode 3840x2160 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output DP-2-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 2883x2160 --rotate normal'
```

After reloading source or opening your next terminal session, you will be able to run monitorsetup1 command.